# Images in CSS don't load with Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I started out with the frontend (HTML, CSS) of my project. Then I made a Flask file containing the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__) 


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(5000)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

index.HTML links to the CSS like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
```

I created the div like so:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div id="hero-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

and in the CSS I call on an image like so:

```
.header-container {
    background-image: url('IMAGENAMEHERE.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh / 9 * 7);
    top: 10px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1000;
```

Since the CSS is in project/static and the image is in project/static/images I also tried:

```
background-image: url('images/IMAGENAMEHERE.jpg');
```

My folder layout is like this (MAC):

```
/project
project.py
/project/static
style.css
/project/static/images
contains the image
/project/templates
index.html
```

I'm very new to flask. This is my first attempt at building a web app.

Thank you!

EDIT================

Also tried:

**Mapstructure:**

```
| myprojectfolder
   - project.py
   - templates/
   - static/
         - style.css
         - images/
              - imagename.jpg
```

**Py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(5000)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

**CSS:**

```
.header-container {
    background-image: url("/static/images/imagename.jpg");
```

================EDIT 2: THE FIX================

On Joost's advice, I moved all images to the static folder. All of a sudden the header loaded. However, the menu images did not, even though they were still pointing to the same exact folder: /static/images/.

You would expect all of them to not work as the images were now in static. I then moved the images back into the images folder and then all images started working. Almost seems like some sort of cache problem.

**Py is now:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(5000)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

I guess here I'm telling flask where the static folder is in relation to the project folder.

Each image in CSS is called like this, which works:

```
background-image: url(/static/images/mobile-Music.png);
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit better what's the error you see?

Comment: I simply see an empty page. In the browser source it does show the image. In console I see Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
background-image: url("/static/images/IMAGENAMEHERE.jpg");
```

Your images has to be here:

`/project/static/images/IMAGENAMEHERE.jpg`

EDIT:

Try this mini example, and place an image called `test.jpg` in your `static/images` folder. I just tried it, and it works perfectly.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/testing')
def testing():
    return render_template_string('<img href="/static/images/test.jpg"/>')
```

Comment: woops, I had `.JPG` in capital and `.jpg` small, so please try it again and make sure that the filenames are 100% identical. Also look at the browser console, and see what error it gives you.

Comment: arch-header2.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: It's very likely that your folder structure is bad, or your filename is incorrect. Try the example I've edited in the answer.

Comment: I did that, the image is in that folder but doesnt show up in the browser: https://puu.sh/BBOiE/88b14ffaad.png. I think you're right about the folder structure being the problem, but it is like I described.
User/project/static/images/test.jpg

Comment: This is all assuming CSS reasons from the project folder. Perhaps it reasons/starts from another one?

Comment: if the `test.jpg` image does not show up in the browser in your example something fishy is going on. It's not CSS related, CSS just uses the address provided, and the problem is with the address. What happens if you make a new app using just the example I provided and nothing else?

Comment: Joost, in terminal I do: export FLASK_APP=test.py, then flask run, server goes up, surfing to localhost:5000 gives "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Comment: go to localhost:5000/testing

Comment: Same result, empty page

Comment: In terminal I get:
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2018 16:51:23] "GET /static/arch-header2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2018 16:51:26] "GET /templates/images/mobile-music.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2018 16:51:26] "GET /templates/images/mobile-food.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2018 16:51:26] "GET /templates/images/mobile-science.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2018 16:51:26] "GET /templates/images/mobile-politics.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: But now your requesting `static/filename.jpg` instead of `static/images/filename.jpg`. You can try to move your image to the static folder, and see if that works.

Comment: Fixed, see my edit. Thank you Joost! You're a hero, even though I don't understand how moving the images back and forth fixed the problem.

Comment: In your request, you request a path to an image, e.g. `/static/images/filename.jpg`. That means, that you app will look in for a static folder, then it will look for a images folder within the static folder, and then it will look for the image in the images folder. If you request `/static/images/filename.jpg`, you need exactly the same folder structure in your app.